# How to change cell color on swipe left in tableView in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have 3 action button in a tableview and I want to change the background color of current cell  on swipe and preselected cell should be reverted if I swipe another cell, background color of only current cell should be changed. I am using *trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt* delegate for swipe actions, but I don't know how to change the background color of the current swiped cell, any idea please help me out.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
        
        let viewButton = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "") {  (contextualAction, view, boolValue) in
            // View action
            print("View action")
            
        }
        viewButton.backgroundColor = .gray
        viewButton.image = UIImage(named: "view")
    
        //Approve
    
        let approveButton = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "") {  (contextualAction, view, boolValue) in
            // Approve action
            print("Approve action")
            
        }
        approveButton.backgroundColor = .gray
        approveButton.image = UIImage(named: "accept")
    
    
        //Reject
    
        let rejectButton = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "") {  (contextualAction, view, boolValue) in
            // Reject action
            print("Reject action")
            
        }
        rejectButton.backgroundColor = .gray
        rejectButton.image = UIImage(named: "reject")
    

        var swipeActions = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [rejectButton, approveButton, viewButton])
        
        swipeActions.performsFirstActionWithFullSwipe = false
        return swipeActions
   }
```

Comment: do you want to change the cell background color when you swipe the cell? Do you have data model for the cell data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willBeginEditingRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
    cell?.contentView.backgroundColor = .red

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didEndEditingRowAt indexPath: IndexPath?) {
    if indexPath != nil {
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath!)
        cell?.contentView.backgroundColor = .red
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a million way to implement the data model. Just to give you an idea, you can change the tableViewCell background color you can use `tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath`:

```
var selectedCell:IndexPath? //this hold the index path of the selected cell 

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
   
    // your code here .....

    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
            if selectedCell == nil {
                print("selected cell is nil")
                //first selection
                cell.backgroundColor = .red
                selectedCell = indexPath
                
            }else{
                if tableView.indexPath(for: cell) != selectedCell {
                    // you are selecting another cell
                    cell.backgroundColor = .red
                    tableView.cellForRow(at: selectedCell!)?.backgroundColor = nil
                    selectedCell = indexPath
                }
            }
      }
}
```